# How to get array out of function in node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

can we access result_cont out of this connection.query function. i want to access this resultant array out of this function.

```
var results = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {


          connection.query( "select c.`uid`, u_p.`first_name`, u_p.`last_name` from `contents` as c inner join `user_profiles` as u_p on u_p.`user_id` = c.`user_id`  where place_id ='"+result[i].id+"' ", handleResults) 

            function handleResults(err_cont, result_cont) {

                results.push(result_cont);
            }
        };

        res.send(results);   // returning empty array []
```

**Edit** Sorry , I forgot to add a loop in my code. now this is actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [async queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queueworker-concurrency):

```
var async = require("async");

var q = async.queue(function (result, callback) {
    connection.query( "select c.`uid`, u_p.`first_name`, u_p.`last_name` from `contents` as c inner join `user_profiles` as u_p on u_p.`user_id` = c.`user_id`  where place_id ='"+result.id+"' ", callback);
}, 2 /* here you can choose concurrency of the queries */);

var results = [];
q.drain = function() {
    console.log("All queries executed %d", results.length);

    // Handle all your results with a simple loop
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      // results[i]
    }
}

// Push all your results to the queue
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

    q.push(result[i], function (err_cont, result_cont) {

      /// Handle each result at the time
      console.log(result_cont );
      results.push(result_cont);
    })
 };
```

Comment: Sorry , I forgot to add a loop in my code. i have update my question. now can you help?

Comment: did't help me out.

how to catch out this need??

var results = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
              

              connection.query( "select c.`uid`, u_p.`first_name`, u_p.`last_name` from `contents` as c inner join `user_profiles` as u_p on u_p.`user_id` = c.`user_id`  where place_id ='"+result[i].id+"' ", handleResults) 

                function handleResults(err_cont, result_cont) {
                    
                    results.push(result_cont);
                }
            };

            res.send(results);

Question Updated..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to chain this callback to another function in order to get the async return value, either use promises or a control flow library like async.js to chain a series of functions together.  And if you just want to print value put console.log inside function body.